# Need a Responsive grid view

Tags: css, flexbox, responsive, column-count

How can I do like the attached picture?? I tried many things but its not working. It only worked when I add column-count. But when I add column-count, the cards show vertically but I need to show horizontally

[image]

Comment: Please add your code as a runnable snippet.

Comment: I just add column-count in the parent div of card div